# With Spring 2 form tags, how can bind list in a list

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have an object with a list of object A with a list of object B.

**Model:**

```
public class ObjectA implements Serializable {

    private List<ObjectB> objectBs;
}

public class ObjectB implements Serializable {

    private String name;
}
```

*with getters and setters*

**DTO:** use in my front end controller with Spring MVC 2

```
public class FrontObject implements Serializable {

    private List<ObjectA> objectAs;
}
```

*with getters and setters*

**In my JSP** (I use forEach tag to add somes stuff, I know the form:checkboxes tag):

```
<c:forEach items="${objectAsList}" var="item">
    <!-- it works -->
    <form:checkbox path="objectAs" value="${item}"/>

    <c:forEach items="${item.objectBs}" var="itemB">
        <!-- whats the path? -->
        <form:checkbox path="????" value="${itemB}" />
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

What's the syntax for the path (of the form tag checkbox) to bind a list of objectB in a list of objectA

Maybe something like

```
<form:checkbox path="objectAs.objectBs" value="${itemB}" />
```

Return org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the path is the name of the value contained by your object. In your case, it's "name"

Comment: No! Its a list in a list. Not one list!

Comment: Do you try with "itemB.name" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be

```
    <form:checkbox path="objectAs.objectBs.name" value="${itemB.name}" />
```

or maybe :

```
    <c:forEach items="${item.objectBs}" var="itemB" varStatus="i">
      <form:checkbox path="objectAs.objectBs[i.index].name" value="${itemB.name}" />
    </c:forEach>
```